# Multi-Axis Graph with Line on top

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, line-plot

I'm attempting to make use of twinx() to create a bar/line combo graph with the line visible on top of the bar. Currently this is how it appears:

[image: Bar/Line Combo]

I also need the line chart to be plotted on the left vertical axis (ax) and the bar on the right (ax2) as it currently is. If I plot the line on the second axis it does appear on top, but obviously it appears on the wrong axis (right)

Here's my code:

```
    self.ax2=ax.twinx()
    df[['Opportunities']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, title=get_title, color='grey', ax=self.ax2, grid=False)
    ax.plot(ax.get_xticks(),df[['Percentage']].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', color='k', linewidth=1.0)
    lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    lines2, labels2 = self.ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc='lower right')
```

Also having trouble with the labels, but one thing at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears, by default, that the artists are drawn on `ax` first, then the
artists on the twin axes `ax2` on top. So since in your code the line plot was drawn on `ax` and the bar plot on `ax2`, the bar plot sits on top of (and obscures) the line.

(I thought I could change this by specifying `zorder`, but that attempt did not
work... )

So one way to solve the problem is to use `ax` to draw the bar plot and `ax2` to draw the line. That will place the line on top of the bars. It will also, by default, place the ytick labels for `ax` (the bar plot) on the left, and the ytick labels for `ax2` (the line) on the right. However, you can use

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")
```

to swap the location of the left and right ytick labels.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)

N = 16
df = pd.DataFrame({'Opportunities': np.random.randint(0, 30, size=N),
                   'Percentage': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=N)},
                  index=pd.date_range('2015-3-15', periods=N, freq='B').date)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df[['Opportunities']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, title='get_title', 
                           color='grey', ax=ax, grid=False)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), df[['Percentage']].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', 
        color='k', linewidth=1.0, label='percentage')

lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc='best')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

Alternatively, the `zorder` of the axes can be set so as to draw `ax` above `ax2`. [Paul Ivanov shows how](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Control-twinx-series-zorder-ax2-series-behind-ax1-series-or-place-ax2-on-left-ax1-on-right-tp12994p12995.html):

```
ax.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder()+1) # put ax in front of ax2
ax.patch.set_visible(False) # hide the 'canvas'
ax2.patch.set_visible(True) # show the 'canvas'
```

Thus,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)

N = 16
df = pd.DataFrame({'Opportunities': np.random.randint(0, 30, size=N),
               'Percentage': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=N)},
index=pd.date_range('2015-3-15', periods=N, freq='B').date)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df[['Opportunities']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, title='get_title', 
                           color='grey', ax=ax2, grid=False)

ax.plot(ax.get_xticks(), df[['Percentage']].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', 
        color='k', linewidth=1.0, label='percentage')

lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc='best')

ax.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder()+1) # put ax in front of ax2
ax.patch.set_visible(False) # hide the 'canvas'
ax2.patch.set_visible(True) # show the 'canvas'

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

yields the same result without having to swap the roles played by `ax` and `ax2`.